# localhost permissions with php mkdir()?

Tags: php, localhost, mkdir

In preparation for my move to a production server later, I'm using this code (php) to make a new directory that will store a user's files:

```
function createNewUserFolder($newUserName)
{
    $siteRoot = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/myWebsite/";
    $newUserSubfolder = $siteRoot . $newUserName;

    if (!mkdir($newUserSubfolder, 0755))
    {
        echo "PROBLEM...";
    }
}
```

I've tried 0644 permissions to no avail -- I only get 'PROBLEM...' when this executes.  I check the string containing the full path and it's correct - "http://localhost/myWebsite/myNewUserSubfolder".

So I'm suspecting the "http://localhost/myWebsite/"  part of the above string is the problem.  Yet I don't see why -- after all, this is php code running on my web server, so why can't my php code create a folder on my web server?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -al` on $siteRoot? And what's the webserver's user called? (Try echo `whoami`)

Comment: try using the real directory ex: /var/www/myWebsite/ with mkdir instead of http:// and see if that works

Comment: ls -l isn't supported on my Windows box, and whoami from the command line yields the user name I created when I set up my user account on this Windows (Vista) box.     Also -- I will try the fully qualified path but my question is -- *should* I be able to use http with /localhost/myWebsite with my call to mkdir() -- if not, why not --- this is a blind spot for me.  The code above could work both on my development and production servers if I figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for windows environments you may want to do something like this

```
$siteRoot = "c:\\path\\to\\siteroot\\myWebsite/";
$newUserSubfolder = $siteRoot . $newUserName;

if (!mkdir($newUserSubfolder, 0755))
{
    echo "PROBLEM...";
}
```

Try that

Or try using FTP if there is FTP support on your server read more here http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: Jaspreet, any relation to Gurbaksh Chahal?  Really cool guy, he grew up 10 minutes away from me here in San Jose (Silicon Valley).  Thanks for your advice here, also @Vyktor, a recurring theme in SO for me is wanting to accept multiple answers but I can't so I up arrowed you and I very much thank you for your help too

Comment: Well I have heard lot about GC. I would say if he would've waited 1 more day on about.me then I would have that domain :) so now I got chahal.me :). Yes he seems to be a cool guy and would love to meet him someday. I wish him all the best and would love to see him someday. But as of today except sharing our surname I don't really know him :(. I live in Melbourne Aus btw. I am glad that I was of any help to you. btw I also run a blog here is url to that http://jaspreetchahal.org. support chahals :)
tah! again
-jas

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create directory via http protocol on "remote server", just try doing in linux shell:

```
 mkdir "http://google.com/mydir"
```

Http server has no way of knowing that it's you and AFAIK it doesn't even support creating directories directly (via http protocol without script).

Anyway `mkdir` works only for the [`file://`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php) protocol (or wrapper if you want) which is implicit in all [file system functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

Therefor when you run `mkdir()` with parameter `/my/path` is evaluated as `file:///my/path` (which it handles correctly). For `http://...` it's just unsupported protocol.